# Make Center Text Alignment Textblock in Grid layout wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, wpf-controls

I have Grid layout with many control inside especially `Textblock` that inside my grid.
But I want to make only in spesific column that has that control to be center text alignment.

You can see my code in grid here..

```
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100">
            <ColumnDefinition.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
                </Style>
            </ColumnDefinition.Resources>
        </ColumnDefinition>
```

I want to make in the second column that I have define all the textbox that occupied in that column could have centered style options. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume your TextBlock belongs to Grid.Column 1

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Grid.Column" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        </Trigger>             
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan.. but How can I style if I my textblock inside of border.. like     `<Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ><TextBlock Text="Minyak tanah" /></Border>` How can I style it?